# get inline js variable in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

```
script.
    var hide_section = 'block';
 .title(style='display:#{hide_section}')
```

I got undefined any idea why? is it because `#{hide_section}` is expecting variable send from the back? I mean controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
script.
    var hide_section = 'block';
.title(style='display:#{hide_section}')
```

Expects the variable to be put at time of compilation i.e. in controller. Whereas by your definition its added to browser's javascript context. You can try following instead.

```
- var hide_section = "block";
.title(style='display:#{hide_section}')
```

It replaces the `hide_section` to give you following

```
<div style="display:block" class="title"></div>
```

Comment: so there is no way i can bind the value coming from controller to cilent side js?

Comment: you can use the method of `script. var hide_section = 'block';` and on client side use jade to compile the template again or use something like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/). Basically you will have to compile template again on client side.